# Python Delete Field from Json File

Tags: python, json

Given a json object of the form :

```
{
   "version": "3.0.0",
   "tags": [
     {
       "name": "Name1"
     },
     {
       "name": "Name2"
     },
     {
       "name": "Name3"
     }
   ]
 }
```

I want to delete all tags which have their names present in a list (eg : ['Name2', 'Name4']) and output the result in another json file.

Output Example :

```
{
   "version": "3.0.0",
   "tags": [
     {
       "name": "Name1"
     },
     {
       "name": "Name3"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple filter and update

```
updated_tags = [d for d in tags if d['name'].upper() not in (tag.upper() for tag in REMOVE_TAGS)]
dict['tags'] = updated_tags
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new tags list and replace it in JSON

```
tags = []
for item in my_json["tags"]:
    if item["name"] not in remove_set:
        tags.append(item)

my_json["tags"] = tags
```

if you want to do it on the actual list

```
for i in range(-1, (-1*len(my_json["tags"])+1),-1): # you need to iterate backwards because you are removing items from list during iteration 
    if my_json["tags"][i]["name"] in remove_set:
        my_json["tags"].pop(i)
```